# Granger Causality Test Derivation

Tags: references, granger-causality

Can anyone recommend a very good textbook or PDF with a full, complete and detailed derivation of the statistical distribution under the null hypothesis of the original Granger Causality Test?

I'm looking for one since weeks and didn't found anything.

Comment: Have you seen Granger's original $1969$ paper and subsequent ones?

Comment: Yes sure i have seen it. The detailed proof is not given (as usual in most original papers). Only the result and some intermediate steps are available.

Comment: I do not have a reference, but the Granger causality test is just a test of a linear restriction on one or more coefficients of a VAR. Therefore, you can search for a detailed presentation of Wald, LM or LR tests for VAR.

Comment: Ok i will take a loot to that. Let me know if you have some very good references on this topic (while i'm searching).